# where should i specify the system.assert in the following code?

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
static TestMethod void insert_update_case() {
        Country_Info__c ctr = new Country_Info__c (Name = 'France',Country_Code_2L__c = 'FR', Language__c = 'Français', Case_RecordType__c = 'FR_Case_RecType');
        insert ctr;
                                                                                       User usr = new User (LastName = 'Rotondo', alias = 'lro', Email = 'lrotondo@rotondo.com', RecordDefaultCountry__c = 'France', BypassVR__c = true, EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', ProfileId = Label.PROFILE_SYSTEM_ADMIN, TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', UserName = 'lrotondo@lrotondo.com');

        System.runAs(usr) {
            Id RTID_COMPANY = [select Id from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Account' and DeveloperName = 'CORE_ACC_Company_Account_RecType' limit 1].Id;
            Id RecordId = [select Id from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Goodwill__c' and Name = 'COMMERCIAL' limit 1].Id;

            Test.startTest();

            Account Acc2 = new Account(Name = 'Test1', Phone = '1000', RecordTypeId = RTID_COMPANY, PersEmailAddress__c = 'test@renault.com', ProfEmailAddress__c = 'addr1@mail.com', ShippingCity = 'Paris', ShippingCountry = 'France', ShippingPostalCode = '75013', ShippingStreet = 'my street');
            insert Acc2;
            Contact Con = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test FirstName', LastName = 'Test Contact', Salutation = 'Mr.', ProEmail__c = 'lro@lro.com', AccountId = Acc2.Id);
            insert Con;
            VEH_Veh__c Vehicule = new VEH_Veh__c (Name = '21342312323123456',  VehicleBrand__c = 'Renault', KmCheck__c = 100 , KmCheckDate__c = date.today());
            insert Vehicule;

            Case Case1 = new Case  (Origin = 'Mobile', Type = 'Information Request', SubType__c = 'Booking', Status = 'Open', Priority = 'Urgent',
                                    Description = 'Description', From__c = 'Customer', Kilometer__c = 1000000, AccountId = Acc2.Id, ContactId = Con.Id,
                                    VIN__c = Vehicule.Id, SuppliedEmail = 'test@renault.com', VIN_Web__c = '21342312323123456');
            insert Case1;

            Goodwill__c g = new Goodwill__c (Case__c = Case1.Id, RecordTypeId = RecordId, ExpenseCode__c = 'OTS', BudgetCode__c = 'Dealer');
            insert g;

            Case1.GWStatus__c = 'Refused';
            update Case1;
            Case1.GWStatus__c = 'Approved';
            update Case1;

            Acc2.CaseNumber__c = Case1.caseNumber;
            update Acc2;

            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dunno how to edit properly !! so pls provide the necessary solution for the above code

Comment: Do you understand WHY you should use system.assert() ? To get the best answer it helps if you ask the most basic question, the single question that will allow you to proceed on your own. Most of the time that isn't how to adapt code,  but to understand what you should be doing.

Comment: yes i know that it is used to check the equality and inequality in a test class to throw an exception if there is any condition fails

Answer (score 0):

When testing, you are testing the logic of your application. To do so, you have to do 2 things:

1. Make your code execute (and have the data it requires to do so)
2. Test that it works by comparing the result to the result you are expecting.

This means that **on every step of your test class**, **where you expect something to happen** by the code you've written (triggers, batches, ..) **you have to verify this**. So on all these places, you should use `System.assert()`, `System.assertEquals()` or `System.assertNotEquals()`.

For instance:

```
Case1.GWStatus__c = 'Refused';
update Case1; //some logic is done here that will populate fields or change something

case1 = [SELECT  relevant fields FROM Case WHERE Id=: case1.id];
SystemAsser( expected value , case1.relevant_field value, 'meaningful message');//VERIFY !
```

Comment: Ok thank you !! that was a clear cut explanation for me.. Will the system.assert have any impact on our class?

Comment: It is essential to your tests, if they are written badly or make the wrong verifications your tests may fail. But that is the entire intention behind testing. Make sure your tests are correct and test how your code should behave, or fix the bugs in your code.